# Method selector with external parameter name in Swift

Tags: swift

What is method selector name (signature) for method with external parameter name in Swift?

```
class Demo: NSObject {

    func sayHello(to person: String, and anotherPerson: String) -> String {
        return "Hello \(person) and \(anotherPerson)!"
    }

}

let object = Demo()

print(object.respondsToSelector("sayHello:to:and:")) // false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to figure that out is to

```
#import "ProjectName-Swift.h"
```

in an Objective-C file, compile the project, and then command-click
on "ProjectName-Swift.h". Then you'll see that the Swift method is
mapped to Objective-C as

```
- (NSString * __nonnull)sayHelloTo:(NSString * __nonnull)person and:(NSString * __nonnull)anotherPerson;
```

and from there you can conclude that the correct select string
is `"sayHelloTo:and:"`:

```
print(object.respondsToSelector("sayHelloTo:and:"))
```

Also note that the selector must have *two* colons, one for each
method parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Try to call like this:

```
object.respondsToSelector(Selector("sayHello:to:and:"))
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: No, i get the same result. Thanks for prompt reply